# boolean or Boolean?

Tags: boolean

I was doing edit reviews on Stack Overflow and found out that people keeps correcting the word "boolean", replacing it with "Boolean" when it appears in text (but not in source code, of course). And then I found out that the spelling checker in my browser agrees with them.

Is there any rationale behind this? It seems grammatically incorrect.

I think the word boolean is used in two different ways, either among programmers as a simple noun, "return a boolean", or as part of a mathematical term, "boolean logic", "boolean algebra". None of these cases seem to motivate a capital letter. You don't write "return a Float", "Fuzzy logic" or "Linear algebra" (unless of course it is at the beginning of a sentence).

I suppose that the capital letter in "Boolean" somehow refers to the name [George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Bool). But then that doesn't make sense either. I found [this link](http://blog.plover.com/lang/Boolean.html) which gives some excellent examples of similar cases, where some term is named after a person, but no capital letter is used.

Any consensus? What is correct? What should we use?

Comment: Wikipedia says ["Boolean"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean), capitalized

Comment: Floats, fuzzy logic and and linear algebra aren't named after anyone.  Boolean logic, Euclidean geometry and Euler's constant are.  If you'd invented something, it might be called Lundinian, not lundinian.

Comment: From the English Language Usage stack exchange -- [Should the word Boolean be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/should-the-word-boolean-be-capitalized)

Comment: @Blrfl See the link posted. "shrapnel", "diesel", "saxophone", "baud", "ampere", "chauvinist", "nicotine" and so on.

Comment: @MichaelT A site where the top answer is stating Wikipedia as an authority of the English language? No thank you :)

Comment: Point taken, although at some point words fall into general use and lose their capitalization.  The OED [treats diesel as an either-or](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52418) but [lists Boolean as capitalized](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21463).  Scientific and mathematical writing tends toward capitalization.  _Boolean_ may lose its capital at some point in the future if people start writing it that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because grammer questions don't belong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any reference that advice *boolean*. You are correct, that it historically dates back to George Boole, but as far as I can tell, all spelling references agree on the adjective as well as the noun being written as *Boolean*.

Here are a few references:

- [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boolean)
- [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boolean)
- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Boolean)
- [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Boolean)
- [Wictionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Boolean)

Feel free to ask on [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/) about the linguistic reasoning behind this, but there seems to be no official authority that accepts the lower-case version. They are all consent on the upper-case variant, so there is currently no reason for me to doubt the correctness of *Boolean*.

Comment: I suppose Oxford is the canonical reference. If they write Boolean there, then that's how it should be spelled, reason be damned. But to me it smells like some mathematician or programmer started to use the term incorrectly, and then it became de facto standard in those technical branches before awareness of the term reached a wider audience. Then perhaps Oxford et al just had to deal with it and go with the capital letter. Just speculation though.

Comment: @Ludin, define "incorrectly".

Comment: I suppose Wictionary is the canonical reference. If they write Boolean there, then that's how it should be spelled, reason be damned. Long live the infallacy of Wikipedia!

Comment: @ThomasEding Yeah right...

Comment: @JeannePindar Incorrectly is how you just spelled my name :) Apart from that, incorrectly as in inconsistent, see the link in the question: "shrapnel", "diesel", "saxophone", "baud", "ampere", "chauvinist", "nicotine".

Comment: Sorry for the name typo, fortunately community editing already sorted it out.